# Can't define set and get methods

Tags: javascript

I have error when try to define property with accessors. Here is my code

```
    var person = {};

    Object.defineProperty(person, 'birthYear', {
        value: 1997,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: false,
        set: function (value) {
            this.birthYear = value;
        },
        get: function() {
            return 'Birth year - ' + this.birthYear;
        }
    });

    console.log(person.birthYear);
```

**The error text:**

> Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value
>   or writable attribute.

If i can't define set and get methods like this how i can do it?

Comment: You'd remove the `value` but you don't want a `birthYear` getter that retrieves `this.birthYear` because that would create infinite recursion. You need to store the value elsewhere, like on a different property name or symbol, or in a variable.

Comment: Is there a reason to define the property on the one object, instead of [the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: ...and FYI, you can do that object creation/definition in one step using `Object.create`.

Comment: @SamOnela Because one does not install arbitrary properties on `Object.prototype`, and the object in the question doesn't have any other prototypes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at the error message:

> Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute.

It doesn't make sense to say if a property is writable when you explicitly state what happens when you try to write it.

So remove:

```
    writable: true,
```

And you can't give it a value, when the value is calculated dynamically when you read it, so remove:

```
    value: 1997,
```

Then you'll get an error about recursion because every time you try to read `person.birthYear`, your getter function tries to read `person.birthYear`.

So store the value somewhere else.

```
var person = { _birthYear: 1997 };

Object.defineProperty(person, 'birthYear', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    set: function (value) {
        this._birthYear = value;
    },
    get: function() {
        return 'Birth year - ' + this._birthYear;
    }
});

console.log(person.birthYear);
```