# "Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute" while getting element via xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, attributes, selenium-chromedriver, accessor

this is my code I want to execute, but I always end up having a weird error I have never seen:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

ends up giving me the error code:

```
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/a because of the following error:
TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute, #<Object>
```

any idea on how i can fix this ?
already tried various solutions, but everything resulted in this error

Update:
here is the HTML code of the element:

```
<div class="FI" data-tooltip="Settings" jslog="85046; u014N:cOuCgd,Kr2w4b,xr6bB;">
  <a class="FH" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Settings">
    <svg class="Xy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" 
     height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
       <path d="M13.85 22.25h-3.7c-.74 0-1.36-.54-1.45-1.27l-.27- 
1.89c-.27-.14-.53-.29-.79-.46l-1.8.72c-.7.26-1.47-.03-1.81-.65L2.2 15.53c-.35-.66-.2-1.44.36-1.88l1.53-1.19c-.01-.15-.02-.3-.02-.46 0-.15.01-.31.02-.46l-1.52-1.19c-.59-.45-.74-1.26-.37-1.88l1.85-3.19c.34-.62 1.11-.9 1.79-.63l1.81.73c.26-.17.52-.32.78-.46l.27-1.91c.09-.7.71-1.25 1.44-1.25h3.7c.74 0 1.36.54 1.45 1.27l.27 1.89c.27.14.53.29.79.46l1.8-.72c.71-.26 1.48.03 1.82.65l1.84 3.18c.36.66.2 1.44-.36 1.88l-1.52 1.19c.01.15.02.3.02.46s-.01.31-.02.46l1.52 1.19c.56.45.72 1.23.37 1.86l-1.86 3.22c-.34.62-1.11.9-1.8.63l-1.8-.72c-.26.17-.52.32-.78.46l-.27 1.91c-.1.68-.72 1.22-1.46 1.22zm-3.23-2h2.76l.37-2.55.53-.22c.44-.18.88-.44 1.34-.78l.45-.34 2.38.96 1.38-2.4-2.03-1.58.07-.56c.03-.26.06-.51.06-.78s-.03-.53-.06-.78l-.07-.56 2.03-1.58-1.39-2.4-2.39.96-.45-.35c-.42-.32-.87-.58-1.33-.77l-.52-.22-.37-2.55h-2.76l-.37 2.55-.53.21c-.44.19-.88.44-1.34.79l-.45.33-2.38-.95-1.39 2.39 2.03 1.58-.07.56a7 7 0 0 0-.06.79c0 .26.02.53.06.78l.07.56-2.03 1.58 1.38 2.4 2.39-.96.45.35c.43.33.86.58 1.33.77l.53.22.38 2.55z"></path>
<circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3.5"></circle></svg></a></div>
```

still getting the error with usage of "visibility_of_element_located"

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for this ?  also, try with `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: Does this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40030083/3710053